# How to join two tables with different ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry that the title of the question is a little bit confusing, but I just cannot find a simple way to summarize the question. Let's start with an example.

There's a product A, and I have to monitor two features X and Y of A. X is generated every day, while Y is generated monthly. In order to save storage, I decide to put X, Y into two tables, namely Table X and Table Y.
So Table X has two columns: date and X; Table Y has two columns: date and Y. However, the date in the two tables are with different frequency. I want to left join the two tables on X, but I need the missing value in Y to be filled with the last month's observation.

Table X is:

```
date                 X
----------      -------------
2019-01-01           1
2019-01-02           2
2019-01-02           3    
   ...              ...
2019-02-01           32
2019-02-02           33
```

Table Y is:

```
date                 Y
----------      -------------
2019-01-01           0
2019-02-01           1
```

Table I want to query is:

```
date                 X              Y
----------      -------------   ----------
2019-01-01           1              0
2019-01-02           2              0
2019-01-02           3              0
   ...              ...            ...
2019-01-31           31             0
2019-02-01           32             1
2019-02-02           33             1
```

Table X:

[image: Table X]

Table Y:

[image: Table Y]

Table I want to query:

[image: Table I want to query]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images,

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I've just modified my question.

Comment: So what actually is the date format in table X and Y? in your images it is 2019/1/1, in your text it is 2019-01-01.

Comment: The date is datetime type data, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT x.date,
       x.x,
       y.y
FROM   x
JOIN   y
  ON   YEAR(x.date) = YEAR(y.date)
 AND   MONTH(x.date) = MONTH(y.date);
```

Comment: You probably need an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Right join and ORDER BY should do it

```
SELECT x.date, x.X, y.Y
FROM X x
RIGHT JOIN Y y ON YEAR(x.date) = YEAR(y.date) AND MONTH(x.date) = MONTH(y.date)
ORDER BY x.date ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
a.Column1, 
a.column2, 
b.column3
FROM tablename LEFT JOIN anothertable b
ON a.column1 = b.column2;
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? I haven't seen columns named like that in the sample data

Comment: well, that was just for reference

Comment: For which reference? For simple joining? How does this handle the requirement of "different ids"?